# Overflow of 32 bit variable

Tags: c

Currently I am implementing an equation `(2^A)[X + Y*(2^B)]` in one of my applications.

The issue is with the overflow of 32 bit value and I cannot use 64 bit data type.

Suppose when `B = 3` and `Y = 805306367`, it overflows 32bit value, but when `X = -2147483648`, the result comes backs to 32 bit range.
So I want to store the result of `(Y*2^B)`. Can anyone suggest some  solution for this.... A and B are having value from `-15` to `15` and `X`,`Y` can have values from `2147483647..-2147483648`.
Output can range from `0...4294967295`.

Comment: If A = B = 15 and X = Y = 2147483647 then the result is far greater than 4294967295. Are there other restrictions that bound the output in the 0...4294967295 range?

Comment: In your equation, is `^` xor, or power?  What do the square brackets represent?

Answer (score 6):

If the number is too big for a 32 bit variable, then you either use more bits (either by storing in a bigger variable, or using multiple variables) or you give up precision and store it in a float.  Since Y can be MAX_INT, by definition you can't multiply it by a number greater than 1 and still have it fit in a 32 bit int.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use loop, instead of multiplication, in this case. Something like this:

```
int newX = X;
int poweredB = ( 1 << B ); // 2^B
for( int i = 0; i < poweredB ; ++i )
{
    newX += Y; // or change X directly, if you will not need it later.
}
int result = ( 1 << A ) * newX;
```

But ***note*** : this will work ***only*** for some situations - only if you have the ***guarantee***, that this result will not overflow. In your case, when Y is large positive and X is large negative number ("large" - argh, this is too subjective), this will definitely work. But if X is large positive and Y is large positive - there will be overflow again. And not only in this case, but with many others.

Comment: +1 for showing that no multiplication is needed, just shifts.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the values for A and B in the assignment I suppose the expected solution would involve this:

- the following are best done unsigned so store the signs for X and Y and operate on their absolute value
- Store X and Y in two variables each, one holding the high 16 bits the other holding the low bits
  something like
  int hiY = Y & 0xFFFF0000;

  int loY = Y & 0x0000FFFF;
- Shift the high parts right so that all the variables have the high bits 0
- Y*(2^B) is actually a shift of Y to the left by B bits. It is equivalent to shifting the high and low parts by B bits and, since you've shifted the high part, both operations will fit inside their 32 bit integer
- Process X similarly in the high and low parts
- Keeping track of the signs of X and Y calculate X + Y*(2^B) for the high and low parts
- Again shift both the high and low results by A bits
- Join the high and low parts into the final result

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use 64-bits because your local C does not support them rather than some other overriding reason, you might consider *The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library* at http://gmplib.org/